# Vertical align three rows in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

This is madness! I have tried adjusting parent to height 100%, wrapping them all in one container, adding classes such as align-self-center, my-auto, align-items-center, etc. But none of them seem to work. My simple layout is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto text-center">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto text-center">
    <p>hello 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto text-center">
    <p>hello 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get these to be vertically centered one after another? Thanks!

Comment: It works as explained in dup: https://www.codeply.com/go/UnTc7u92GT

Comment: That worked, I think my problem was that my body and html werent actually getting set to height: 100vh until i did it inline on the body tag. Weird. Thanks!